# Is setting your Facebook profile public to search engines ever advantageous?

Tags: background-check, online-presence

I was fiddling with my Facebook security and privacy settings when I stumbled to this option (which I wasn't aware was controllable!).

[image: Search engine enabling]

### Question :

Assume a decent Facebook profile for a work setting. (No inappropriate content)

Is making your Facebook profile public help you in getting hired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather keep the Facebook account private, why increase any attack vectors?

Contrary to popular belief, employers ultimately look at "what you know" and how that helps their "bottom line" rather than if you are an interesting person.

Answer (score 3):

> Is making your Facebook profile public help you in getting hired?

It would depend entirely on the contents of your Facebook, and the propensity of your prospective employers to search for, and read your Facebook.

Most folks these days seem to view Facebook more as a personal-social site, while something like LinkedIn is viewed as more professional-social. Employers may well view your Facebook, but it perhaps has less importance professionally.

Assuming everything you have ever posted on Facebook reflects well on you professionally, it probably couldn't hurt. (As @keshlam correctly points out in his comment - that's a rather large assumption).

Comment: However, that may be a very large assumption, given the way most folks use Facebook. Which is one of several reasons I barely use Facebook.

Comment: As you've said, Facebook is a personal social networking site. It has no real benefit in the employment arena unless the job being applied for is specifically a corporate social networking position with in a marketing department. The possibility of detritus deposited on a timeline by those few friends we all have who just don't "get it" can be far more damaging than any possible gain by something positive.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine any way that it would help you.

Something like LinkedIn makes perfect sense, because this gives an employer information about you that is actually relevant to the hiring process.  If you have a public Facebook profile I can't imagine what you could possibly have on it that would positively influence a hiring decision.

So my advice would be: if your profile really does have nothing inappropriate on it, it won't affect hiring in anyway.  I can only see Facebook profiles affecting hiring in negative ways.  Keep it public or private, it's up to you, but I would err on the side of caution and make it private.